# NopCommerce : Display most viewed products on category home page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I am using NopCommerce. I want to display top 10 most viewed products on category home page.
so category home page will show the most viewed 10 products of that category.

How can i display most viewed products on category home page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add a new entity or add a new field in existing entity.
[how to add new entity](http://mycodingerrors.blogspot.in/2012/06/how-to-add-new-tables-to-nopcommerce.html)
and create method for get result of count most viewed products.
then call function on products view page.